# Servicemix - Expose CXF Endpoint in SOAP 1.2

Tags: java, soap, cxf, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

I'm trying to expose a WS in SOAP 1.2 in my servicemix (Fuse based).

I've declare the CXF endpoint in my blueprint configuration file :

```
  <camelcxf:cxfEndpoint id="wsIdentService"
    serviceClass="service.ident.IdentService"
    address="/ws/ident"
    serviceName="ws:IdentService"
    endpointName="ws:IdentEndpoint"
    xmlns:ws="http://company.com/core/ident/0.1/"
```

I've tried several options :

- adding wsdlURL in endpoint definition leads to a `org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not find definition for port ...`
- adding `<camelcxf:binding><soap:soapBinding mtomEnabled="true" version="1.2"/></camelcxf:binding>` leads to a `NullPointerException at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.RecipeBuilder.getValue`

Does anyone ever succeed to expose a CXF service in servicemix with SOAP 1.2 supports ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is available only with camel 2.10 and thus with servicemix 4.5